# Which name should I choose for private abstract functionality with a public proxy?

Tags: scala

I have an abstract class implementing some concrete functionality for its child classes:

```
abstract class Function {
  def eval: Double = some_concrete_functionality_which_calls_fEval
  def simplify: Funcion = more_concrete_calling_fSimplify

  protected def fEval: Double
  protected def fSimplify: Funcion
}
```

The child classes should implement `fEval` and `fSimplify` themselves, while `eval` and `simplify` act like a public proxy between them to provide common functionality before calling the actual implementation.

`f` stands for function but, although I feel `fName` is not very expressive, I can't think of any good alternatives (besides `concreteEval` which seems very bloated.)

Any suggestions? Should I stick to `concreteEval`? Maybe keep it like it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it's more a matter of taste. If I were to come along behind you, I wouldn't have any particular problem with `fEval` and `fSimplify`.

I'm not sure that I would like `concreteEval`.

In my own code I tend to use `doEval`, but I could also imagine using `evalImpl` or `myEval`, depending on what it is exactly that is being done by these functions.

Comment: I thought about `myEval` too but it looks very meaningless. Why it it 'yours'? Like `fEval` it doesn't explain why it is not just `eval`. `doEval` and `evalImpl` look good, they show that it's where you actuall **do** the eval and that it's an **impl**, respectively. I'll think of them. Thanks!